# Is there a Bash oneliner to numerically change a piped input according to the function: `if x = 0, f(x) = 1, else f(x) = 0`?

Tags: bash

I've got the following function:

```
function vmrunning(){
   return $(vboxmanage list runningvms | grep "$1" | wc -l | xargs)
}
```

However, this doesn't do what I want because it returns 0 when the vm is not running and 1+ when the vm is running. I need it to do the opposite. i can do this with an if statement easily--even in one line--but is there something I could do with `bc`, `expr`, or even `not` to flip the value to return it correctly?

EDIT:

I realized I can just do the below, but for the sake of the pursuit of knowledge, is there a way to do the above?

```
function vmrunning(){
   vboxmanage list runningvms | grep "$1" > /dev/null
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an arithmetic context like `$((...))` there's a `!` operator that works just like C's.

```
function vmrunning(){
   return $(( ! $(vboxmanage list runningvms | grep "$1" | wc -l | xargs) ))
}
```

The simplest way is to use `grep -q`:

```
function vmrunning(){
   vboxmanage list runningvms | grep -q "$1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks also for the `-q`. I had forgotten about that.